# An HTML5 document can be written using HTML or XHTML syntax

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML via a workbook that I've paid for. In it it says  "An HTML5 document can be written using HTML or XHTML syntax"...Is this true? I thought an HTML5 document could only be written in HTML5!? I know that by using `<!DOCTYPE html>` I'm declaring that the document is written in HTHL5. I know XHTML has a different document declaration, so it's not like I'm going to head up my page with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and then use XHTML as my syntax...

Comment: Yeah, I'm happy to use HTML5 (that's what the book recommends too)...I'm just confused because the book is implying that if I use XHTML then it can still be classed as an HTML5 document, which doesn't seem right to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this means is that you can use XHTML syntax if you like. For example, both of these are fine:

```
 <meta charset="utf=8">

 <meta charset="utf=8" />
```

The single doctype of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

covers both. They are BOTH HTML5!

Where you really need to be careful though is that ONLY elements that are defined as elements with no content are allowed to use the self-terminating syntax. This would be elements like: img, br, meta and link. If an element is declared in the spec. as a content element, it can't be self-terminated:

```
<p /> is incorrect
```

Comment: I was leaving a more verbose response, but this covers it. HTML is more forgiving than XHTML, and there was, once upon a time, a big fight brewing between the W3C, who wanted to abandon HTML for XHTML, and the WHATWG, who ultimately prevailed, and they were working on separate standards.